# Apache Camel triggers the send of an inbound file before the write operation has completed

Tags: parameters, apache-camel

I have several files that are inbound to a folder on my server that has Apache Camel loaded. Some of the larger files are being triggered to send before the write operation has completed. This results in the customer at the final destination receiving incomplete files. I have attempted to use the readLock parameters, but it seems anything in excess of 200K is still being triggered to start the send operation even though the write operation has not finished.

I tried this and it still sends the files larger than 200K before the write operation has finished:

Comment: You should probably show how you configured your routes and how you read those files. Also, where are you reading your files from? Local file system? EFS? Remote SFTP Server? Or something else? If the current readLock implementations aren't sufficient for you, you could always write your own one. It is not that hard, actually. But I have to admit, haven't used Camel in a while now